# Como ejecutar una funcion despues de otra react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

hola tengo una consulte tengo una funcion que reponde a un server por lo que tarda un poco y cuando intenta ejecutar la otra funcion salta error, ya que la funcion que responde al server da un array y cuando la otra funcion lo pide todavia no lo tiene como podria solucionar esto ej:

```
responseServer(tarea) {
     return fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({ refresh: false })
        global.refresh = false
        let data = [];
        let Milestone = [];

        Object.values(responseJson.summary).forEach(item => {
          data = data.concat(item);
        });

        const result = ["Milestone"]
          .reduce((total, category) => ({
            ...total,
            [category]: data.filter(line => line.includes(category)) 
          }), {})

        Object.values(result.Milestone).forEach(item => {
          Milestone = Milestone.concat(item)
        });

        this.setState({
          Milestone: Milestone
        })
      })
}
```

y la otra

```
sacarPorcentaje(item) {
 this.responseServer(item)
 let summaryCopy = this.state.Milestone.map(data => {return data.split(",")})
      console.log(summaryCopy)
      var Okeys = 0;
      var total = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < summaryCopy.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < summaryCopy[i].length; j++){
          if(summaryCopy[i][j] === "OK") {
            Okeys = Okeys + 1
          }
        }
        total = total + 1 
      }
      console.log(Okeys)
      console.log(total)
}
```

Comment: y tambien el sacarporccentaje() esta en el render

Answer (score 0):

si a lo que te refieres es que primero necesitas esperar a que la funcion `responseServer()` se ejecute y una vez que termine quieres que continue la ejecucion de `sacarPorcentaje()`, entonces necesitas agregar un async/await a la funcion de la siguiente manera:

```
async sacarPorcentaje(item) {
  await this.responseServer(item);
  // aqui va lo demás
}
```

Espero haber ayudado :)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el metodo componentDidUpdate. Que se ejecuta siempre que cambia algo en el estado o en las props y añadir un if para controlar el cambio de estado de la variable Milestone.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    if(this.state.Milestone && prevState.Milestone !== this.state.Milestone){
        sacarPorcentaje("parametro que sea");
    }
}
```